# How to use cam with matlab under Ubuntu16.04

Tags: matlab, camera

My os is Ubuntu16.04, and Matlab vision is 2015b, I installed OS Generic Video Interface and USB Webcams,and I got this after run `imaqhwinfo`:

```
InstalledAdaptors: {'dcam'  'gentl'  'gige'  'linuxvideo'}
    MATLABVersion: '8.6 (R2015b)'
      ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
   ToolboxVersion: '4.10 (R2015b)'
```

but while I run `obj = videoinput('linuxvideo',1);preview(obj);`I got this:

`Error using videoinput (line 233) There are no devices installed for the specified ADAPTORNAME. See IMAQHWINFO.`

and I also cannot run webcam:
`No webcams have been detected. Please ensure the webcam is connected to the system.`
how to solve this ? thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you ensured that the webcam is really connected? Are you able to use webcam for any other application?

Comment: yes,I'm sure, I wrote a python file to use my computer's camera and it ran successfully.